# Visual Studio execution closes when pressing enter

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hello im trying to learn C# step by step. I installed Visual Studio to practice but 20 mins in I cant test my basic code when executing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("What is your name?");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("My name is " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

It is as basic as this but when I execute and type a name and press enter, the cmd just closes. any help would be appreciated because i am enthusiastic to start out with C#

[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUF3n.jpg)

Comment: Put `Console.ReadLine()` after the `WriteLine` so that the console app stays open until you press enter a **second** time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Main method returns after

```
Console.WriteLine("My name is " + name);
```

And this effectively terminates the app.
You should put a

```
Console.Read();
```

to wait until the next keystroke.

Answer (score 1):

Add another input to close application, so cmd wont close until you press enter again.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("What is your name?");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("My name is " + name);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **Ctrl + F5**

If you don't need to debug, then Ctrl-F5 is the best option

works automatically without any Console.Readline() or ReadKey()

Visual Studio will keep the console window open, until you press a key.